# nonComVisibleBaseClass Error when moq a Com interface

Tags: moq, castle-dynamicproxy

I used moq version 4.0.10827 to mock an Com object and when i upgrade to 4.2.1510.2205 i get an nonComVisibleBaseClass error when the test execute:

```
[Guid("0339CD56-9BA3-477D-801B-E5F73D37EABE")]
[TypeLibType(4160)]
public interface IDaemonCli
{
    // methods & propperties ...
    [DispId(1)]
    void CloseLog();
   ....
}

[CoClass(typeof(DaemonCliClass))]
[Guid("0339CD56-9BA3-477D-801B-E5F73D37EABE")]
public interface DaemonCli : IDaemonCli
{
}

[ClassInterface(0)]
[Guid("D94FBC81-06EC-4EAA-B73F-794051487691")]
[TypeLibType(2)]
public class DaemonCliClass : IDaemonCli, DaemonCli
{
    // ... definitions of all methods of the com obj
   [DispId(1)]
   public virtual void CloseLog();
   ....
}
```

The mock is created as this :

```
[TestClass]
[Serializable]
public abstract class Test : IDisposable
{
     protected static Mock<DaemonCli> DaemonClientMock { get; private set; }
     static Test()
    {
        Test.DaemonClientMock = new Mock<DaemonCli>();
        // here are all the setup on the DaemonClientMock
    }
}
```

The mock is injected in the tested code as this :

```
typeof(LoggedServiceBase).GetProperty(
            PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => this.batchClassService.Logger),
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .SetValue(this.batchClassService, Test.DaemonClientMock.Object, null);
```

The Exception is raised when the mock is used by the tested class:

```
freeMindCom.SetLog(this.Logger);
```

All was fine with the version of Castle used by the previous version of Moq (4.0.10.827), i don't know precisely which one it was.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks